# Skype for business online - botframework with voice

Tags: botframework

Is it possible to handle voice in a S4B online chat bot?
I know that is possible to handle voice creating your own application (via directline) and using Bing Speech API (or CRIS), also using S4B onpremise via UCMA, but I'm not sure about S4B online.